# TYPO3 Rich Text Editor (RTE) in fullscreen mode works, but not in my Extension?

Tags: typo3, fullscreen, rich-text-editor, typo3-extensions, extension-builder3

At my standard content elements `text & media` the fullscreen mode for RTE (`htmlarea`, Rich-Text-Editor) is working fine.

But - I've wrote an extension (via extension builder) and if I try to use the RTE in fullscreen, I've got the following error:

```
Module wizard_rich_text_editor is not configured
```

Here's my TCA, where's my error? The 'TYPO3-RTE' is working fine, so there must be an error in my following code. What do you think?

```
    'description' => array(
        'exclude' => 1,
        'label' => 'LLL:EXT:xyz/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_xyz_domain_model_product.description',
        'config' => array(
            'type' => 'text',
            'cols' => 40,
            'rows' => 15,
            'eval' => 'trim',
            'wizards' => array(
                'RTE' => array(
                    'icon' => 'wizard_rte2.gif',
                    'notNewRecords'=> 1,
                    'RTEonly' => 1,
                    'module' => array(
                        'name' => 'wizard_rich_text_editor',
                        'urlParameters' => array(
                            'mode' => 'wizard',
                            'act' => 'wizard_rte.php'
                        )
                    ),
                    'title' => 'LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_ttc.xlf:bodytext.W.RTE',
                    'type' => 'script'
                )
            )
        ),
    ),
```

Does anyone know the problem? Thanks for your help.

Regards,
Stefan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A working example for TYPO3 7.x and 8 is

```
    'bodytext' => [
        'exclude' => 0,
        'l10n_mode' => 'noCopy',
        'label' => 'LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xlf:bodytext_formlabel',
        'config' => [
            'type' => 'text',
            'cols' => 30,
            'rows' => 5,
            'softref' => 'rtehtmlarea_images,typolink_tag,images,email[subst],url',
            'wizards' => [
                '_PADDING' => 2,
                'RTE' => [
                    'notNewRecords' => 1,
                    'RTEonly' => 1,
                    'type' => 'script',
                    'title' => 'Full screen Rich Text Editing',
                    'icon' => 'EXT:backend/Resources/Public/Images/FormFieldWizard/wizard_rte.gif',
                    'module' => [
                        'name' => 'wizard_rte',
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ]
    ],
```

The name should be `wizard_rte`.